# How best to structure class heirachy in C# to enable access to parent class members?

Tags: c#

I am having a couple of issues deciding how best to describe a certain data structure in C# (.NET 3.5).

I have to create a class library that creates some text files for the input of a command line program. There are dozens of file types, but most of them have a similar header, footer and a couple of other properties.

So a file might look like this:

```
timestamp filename company

....lots of attributes that make up the file body....

footerdetail1 footerdetail2 footerdetail3
```

Now out of these dozens of file types there are really only three unique header/footer combos.

So I want to make a parent class that contains most of the headerItems and footeritems, and then implement the actual file types in a derived class:

```
class BaseFileType {

public List<HeaderItems>; 
public List<BodyItems>;   
public List<FooterItems>;
FileType filetype;
String filename;

public BaseFileType1 (FileType filetype,String filename) {

   this.filetype = filetype;
   this.filename = filename;


   // add stuff to the header list
   // add stuff to the footer list


} 

    // some methods to find items in the header/ footer lists

}

class ActualFile1 : BaseFileType {

    ActualFile() {


    //add stuff to the bodyitems list
    }


    //some other generic methods


}
```

The thing is, I want to inherit the contructor from the base class for the derived class, but from what I have read this can not be done. What is the best strategy here?

I have seen that I can call the base constructor from my derived class constructor like so:

ActualFile() : base (parent parameters)

Is this even the best way to go about my task?  In the end I am just looking for the best data structures for all of this file information so I dont need to repeat myself when I make these classes.

What other alternatives to people thing would work? Have a single FileFactory that spits out classes containing the structure I require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like something a Template Method would solve... (Finally a place to use a pattern :)

```
public abstract class DocumentGenerator
{
  abstract protected void AddHeader();
  abstract protected void AddBody();
  abstract protected void AddFooter();

  // Template Method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern
  public FileInfo Generate(string sFileName)
  {
    FileInfo f = null;  
    //create file

    // either pass in the file to the below methods or use member vars + an additional write step 
    AddHeader();
    AddBody();
    AddFooter();

    // write out everything to the file
    return f;
  }
}
```

Next for each of the 3 unique combination, intermediate level classes like

```
abstract public class UniqueHeaderFooterCombination1 : DocumentGenerator
{
  protected override void AddHeader()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("unique combination1 header");
  }
  protected override void AddFooter()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("unique combination1 footer");
  }
}
```

Finally the concrete classes for each unique filetype

```
public class LetsSayCSVGenerator : UniqueHeaderFooterCombination1
{
  protected override void AddBody()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("csv body items");
  }
}
```

Couple this with a Factory to return the right type of Generator for a FileType and you're done.

```
abstract class DocumentGeneratorFactory
{
  public static DocumentGenerator GetGenerator(FileType eFileType)
  {
    switch (eFileType)
    {
      // a hash of FileType => Generator
      default:
        return new LetsSayCSVGenerator();
    }

  }
}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    DocumentGenerator d = DocumentGeneratorFactory.GetGenerator(FileType.CSV);
    FileInfo f = d.Generate("ItsAlive.CSV");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, constructors are not inherited.

Forcing the derived class to supply the details in the constructor would be the ideal case if you need to know the values during construction. If you don't, consider an abstract property that the derived class must provide:

```
// base-class
public abstract FileType FileType {get;}

// derived-class
public override FileType FileType {
    get {return FileType.Excel;} // or whatever
}
```

Note that unless you document it **very** clearly (and understand the implications) you shouldn't call a virtual method (such as the above) inside the constructor (since the derived type's constructor hasn't executed yet) - but it is fine after that.

Since the file-name isn't really dependent on the sub-type, I suspect I would leave that as a ctor parameter either way.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your base class that reads the headers & footers, and provides access to the attributes in the middle.  Then define an interface that the dozens of specific attribute readers will implement.  The interface could require accepting a "base class" and each implementation would define how the stuff in the middle is read.

In practice, you'd have a common way to read the common parts and a common way to access the attributes.  This parts are loosely coupled so changes would be less restrictive.